# Disable "development mode" warning in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm running Vue in development mode, and I get this message every time I load the page:

> "You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on
>   production mode when deploying for production. See more tips at
>   https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html"

Is there a way to disable it without switching to production mode?

Comment: Including minified vuejs ?

Comment: in vue-cli/webpack development environment?

Comment: yeah, that should do the trick

Comment: so i should remove vue from the installed npm packages (without removing any dependants), remove the reference to it in the package.json file, include it manually in index.html file and expect all the other packages that depend on Vue to magically function properly? have you ever used npm?

Comment: If you include it manually in your index.html, obviously other part's that depends on vue won't work.If you take look at the node_modules directory and find vue, go to the dist directory and there you'll see vue.min.js file, which you need somehow include into your app.

Comment: 'somehow include'. i'll just write `somehow include 'vue.min.js';` that should work.

Comment: Don't really understand your point here.First thing, I don't see reason why you want to disable this warn on development mode, it's not any kind of error or something.Second I give you one way to get rid of this - that's using minified Vue version, but then you will loose some cool warning when you maybe make some mistake in code.

Comment: 1. I can't use minified version unless I either a) remove all components that depend on vue or b) include all components manually (defeating the purpose of vue-cli automated setup). and 2. i don't want to disable the development mode, I only want to disable the ONE warning about development mode. If you don't know the answer, it's best not to post anything.

Comment: First, I wan't sure at the begining does we mean on same thing, and then I give you suggestion about using minified version of vue, but then you'll loose cool warnings.Second thing upvotes from comments doesn't increase my reputation, so I don't understand this part.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As of Vue.JS 2.2.0 the development warning can be disabled as follows:

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

should be added to main.js (or main.ts if using TypeScript)

Comment: However, I am sure about this `Vue.config.productionTip`  switched to `false`, I receive the following error in browser's console:
_[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "selected"_

Comment: that doesn't seem like a related issue. usually it happens if you're assigning something to a prop inside a component.

Comment: This answer don't work for me. After of adding `Vue.config.productionTip = false` remains the message.

Comment: @Ebrahim you're passing `name` as prop in your HelloWorld component, and using it in v-model in the same component, hence the warning, unrelated to this issue.

Comment: @skpblack are you on Vue 2.2.0 or higher?

Answer (score 7):

Open file app.js and add the next code

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

[image]

Read more in [Vue Api](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#productionTip)

Answer (score 5):

In Vue 3, `Vue.config.productionTip = false` has been removed without an alternative to disable the "development mode" warning (see [Vue 3 Migration Guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#config-productiontip-removed)).

Answer (score -3):

If you are using VueCli and package.json file like this:

Then remove --mode development from line number 7 : [image: change line number 7]

**Like this :** "build": "vue-cli-service build"