# You are running Vue in development mode

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

i get this message everytime i load the page:

You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production. see more tips at ....

and i saw someone's solution to put a code in app.js , like this :

```
  Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

can someone please help?

Comment: That's the right way to disable the tip.  It might help to edit your post with info about your Vue version, dev environment, and show how you used it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable "development mode" warning in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743926/disable-development-mode-warning-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 1):

As the message says it is because you are running a non-compiled version of Vue for development.

If you are in development, it is not necessary to pay attention to this message.

However, if you have a web site in production, it is recommended that you compile the assets for production with the command `npm run prod` or `npm run production`.

If you want to develop without seeing this message you have to locate where you create the Vue instance and place the line after importing like this

```
const Vue = require('vue');

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var  app = new Vue({
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are building in development mode, to build to production you should use `npm run production`

Comment: "*Why is this appearing in the console?*" doesn't seem to be the question the OP is asking, instead it seems to be more of a "*where do I put this line of code to stop the message appearing?*"

Answer (score 0):

In your file structure, if you open node_modules > vue > dist you will see several js files and different versions of Vue. Whatever npm build script you are running is compiling a non-minified version (most likely /vue.js).

Instead of running this build, run or create a different script that instead builds /vue.min.js instead.